# mysql reduces the int number to 2 digits

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I am importing data from a csv file

my table structure is , all fields are of type int

```
 CREATE TABLE `user_asset_data` (
 `age_id` int(12) NOT NULL,
 `system_id` int(12) NOT NULL,
 `loc_id` int(12) NOT NULL,
 `poi_id` int(11) default NULL )
```

my csv file

```
 1,1,38491,50454
2,1,43086,49230
3,1,45455,51906
4,1,31516,50786
5,1,45532,54867
6,1,47991,57207
7,1,50261,58576
8,1,43443,48475
9,1,41378,47573
```

the sql command

```
'load data local infile "data.csv" into table `' user_table`
fields terminated by ','
optionally enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\r\n' '
```

The issue mysql reduces the int to 2 digits

so the 38491 becomes 38 !

```
1,1,38,50
2,1,43,49
3,1,45,51
4,1,31,50
5,1,45,54
6,1,47,57
7,1,50,58
8,1,43,48
9,1,41,47
```

Comment: Might be a typo, but the table you created isn't the one your 'load data' statement is filling?

Comment: Are you sure that CSV file is exactly what you'd see in a text editor? There's no possibility that the numbers are saved on lines like: `1,1,"38,491","50,454"` ? This would make sense as MySQL would be converting these numbers into integers to save them.

Comment: @scragar yes your are correct